# Nextjs is not rendering dynamic meta tags with the data using serverSideProps

Tags: reactjs, next.js, getserversideprops

hello folks i need some help regarding SEO in nextjs
i am trying it for like 2 weeks or so but unable to do so
i am getting the data from the backend in serverSideProps it is successfully loading the page but the crawlers are unable to pick it up they don't show any thing.
at First i wrote my component, that didn't worked

```
import React from 'react';
import Head from 'next/head';

const MetaPreviewComponent = ({url = "https://elementsdistro.com/", type = "website", title, summary, imageUrl}) => {
  return (
    <Head>
      <title>Social Media Preview</title>
      <meta property="og:url" content={url}/>
      <meta property="og:type" content={type}/>
      <meta property="og:title" content={title}/>
      <meta name="twitter:card" content={summary}/>
      <meta
        property="og:description"
        content="this is working properly, the description"
      />
      <meta property="og:image" content={imageUrl || 'https://www.example.com/images/placeholder.jpg'}/>
    </Head>
  );
};

export default MetaPreviewComponent;
```

now i am trying with the next-seo but same thing.
attached screenshot is a page component living in the prodcuts/[product].js

any help would be highly highly appreciated, if you can even point me in the right direction I'll be very grateful to you.

[image]

Comment: Please use code snippets, do _not_ use images for code.

Comment: What do you mean by "crawlers are unable to pick it up they don't show any thing"? If you inspect the page's source, can you verify your meta tags are present there?

Comment: Check the first request that goes out when you request for the page, If the meta tags are present in the server rendered page. Then you should be good. If not, then you should check your robots & search console.

Comment: this problem was only with the safari somehow. there was a substring method call in place, because of which it was not working properly, as soon as i removed that it was rendering the page.